# How to disable 'zip' warning in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, zip

I want to zip a file using bash shell, so I used:

```
echo -n 'Insert the file path:'
read path
echo 'Hello World' > ${path}
zip -u ${path}.zip ${path}
```

When I run this script, it gives me a warning:

```
zip warning: test.zip not found or empty
adding: test (deflated 66%)
```

It works just fine but how can I disable this warning? Am I using `zip` in right way?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think you want the quiet flag.

```
zip -uq ${path}.zip ${path}
```

From the man pages:

> ```
> -q
> --quiet
>           Quiet   mode;  eliminate  informational  messages  and  comment
>           prompts.  (Useful, for example, in shell scripts and background
>           tasks).
> ```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try "add" instead of update(-u) ?

from man page:

> ```
>    add
>           Update existing entries and add new files.  If the archive does not exist
>           create it.  This is the default mode.
>
>    update (-u)
>           Update existing entries if newer on the file system and  add  new  files.
>           If the archive does not exist issue warning then create a new archive.
>
>    freshen (-f)
>           Update  existing entries of an archive if newer on the file system.  Does
>           not add new files to the archive.
>
>    delete (-d)
>           Select entries in an existing archive and delete them.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should not tell `zip` to update an archive (`-u`). Without the `-u` switch `zip` tries to add files to an archive, and should create non-existing archives without warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove unnecessary output lines and leave normal status info visible, but you first need to redirect the stderr to stdout. For example following command will extract from many zip files only some specific files, but will not show emnpty lines nor complain for not found files. In that way you still have some output for logging, debugging etc.

```
unzip -jn archivedlogfiles\* \*logfile\* 2>&1 | grep -vE '^$|^caution.*'
Archive:  archivedlogfiles1.zip
  inflating: little_logfile_20160515.log
  inflating: little_logfile_20160530.log
Archive:  archivedlogfiles2.zip
Archive:  archivedlogfiles3.zip
Archive:  archivedlogfiles4.zip
Archive:  archivedlogfiles5.zip
Archive:  archivedlogfiles6.zip
Archive:  archivedlogfiles7.zip
Archive:  archivedlogfiles8.zip
  inflating: little_logfile_20160615.log
  inflating: little_logfile_20160630.log
Archive:  archivedlogfiles9.zip
2 archives were successfully processed.
7 archives had fatal errors.
```

Basically your command would then look like this:

```
zip -u ${path}.zip ${path} 2>&1 | grep vE '^zip\swarning.*'
```